# When is Unicode code point same as Mathematica CharacterCode?

Tags: unicode, string-manipulation

For what characters c does `CharacterCode[c]` not return the same value as c's Unicode code point?  How does one convert c to its Unicode code point with Mathematica in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

For a character in range U+0000 to U+D7FF or U+E000 to U+FFFF, `ToCharacterCode[c]` will just return the same value as c's Unicode code point.

For a character in range U+10000 to U+10FFFF, `ToCharacterCode[c]` will return two numbers, and Mathematica will take it as two characters.

For example:

```
In[1]:= ToCharacterCode /@ {"$", "€", "", ""}

Out[1]= {{36}, {8364}, {55297, 56375}, {55378, 57186}}

In[2]:= StringLength@""

Out[2]= 2
```

In fact, the Unicode code point of "" is U+10437, which is 66615 in decimal. And `{55297, 56375}` is just `IntegerDigits[66615 - 65536, 1024] + {55296, 56320}`.

The following function can convert a Unicode code point to the corresponding Mathematica CharacterCode.

```
If[# < 65536, {#}, IntegerDigits[# - 65536, 1024] + {55296, 56320}] &
```

Comment: What about the characters between U+D7FF and U+E000?

Comment: @qazwsx They are not assigned to characters.

Comment: 55296 is 0xD800.  What's 56320?

Comment: @qazwsx 0xDC00.

Comment: I know, but why 0xDC00?

Comment: @qazwsx When a character is represented by two 16-bit code units, the first will be in the range 0xD800..0xDBFF, and the second will be in the range 0xDC00..0xDFFF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF

Comment: Uh... this question ask for char -> Unicode codepoint, not vice versa.